# How to parse all the XML tags in Python?

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I want to parse the XML file entirely and extract the values of all the tags. I have the code for extracting the values for the tags which i mentioned. But i want to extract all the values of all the tags. Manually mentioning all the tags and extracting is impossible right? That's why i need to know a way to do. Pls help me out.

Thanks in advance.!!

PYTHON CODE :

```
from xml.dom import minidom
document = minidom.parse("forms.xml")

def findChildNodeByName(parent, name):
    for node in parent.childNodes:
            if node.nodeType == node.ELEMENT_NODE and         node.localName == name:
                    return node
    return None

def getText(nodelist):
    rc = []
    for node in nodelist:
            if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
                    rc.append(node.data)
    return ''.join(rc)

 titles =[]

servers = document.getElementsByTagName('servers')

for server in servers:
        item1 = server.getElementsByTagName("server")
        print item1
        for item2 in item1:
                value = item2.getElementsByTagName("host")   [0].childNodes[0].data
            print value
            titles.append(value)


print titles
```

XML FILE :

```
    <servers>
      <server>
        <host> HOST1 </host>
       <port> 6667 </port>
        <channel>
          <name> CHANNAME1</name>
        </channel>
       <channel>
          <name> CHANNAME2 </name>
        </channel>
  </server>
      <server>
<host> HOST2 </host>
<port> 6667 </port>
<channel>
  <name> CHANNAME3 </name>
</channel>
```

OUTPUT :

```
HOST1
HOST2
```

Comment: @JohnZwinck I appreciate yo idea.! But i specifically want it in Python.

Comment: Help us help you. Show the code you have so far, and exactly how that falls short of what you want. Have you searched for Python XML libraries? Was there something specific in them that you couldn't make sense of?

Comment: "Manually mentioning all the tags and extracting is impossible right?" -- I don't know what this was intended to mean. As Edward said, show us what you're actually trying to do -- a small sample of the kind of input you're trying to handle, how you're trying to handle it, what results you're getting, and what results you need.

Comment: @Edward  I have posted the python code and xml file that i used for parsing.. You can see the code that i have mentioned the tag name ("host") to retrieve value from that particular tag.

Comment: @keshlam I have posted everything you asked for..!! Thank you in advance...!!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds `lxml.etree.iterparse()` is your friend.

To (roughly) quote from the documentation (any added bugs my own):

```
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

xml = '''
<root>
  <element key='value'>text</element>
  <element>text</element>tail
  <empty-element xmlns="http://testns/" />
</root>
'''

context = etree.iterparse(StringIO(xml))
for action, elem in context:
    print("%s: %s (attribs: %r; text: %r)"
          % (action, elem.tag, elem.attrib, elem.text))
```

...will iterate through each element, showing its attributes and text. Notably, the code in this example does not hardcode the names (`element`, `key`, `empty-element`, etc).

If you care about context, use a stack to record which elements you're inside of (have seen actions of `start` but not `end` for).

Comment: i am a newbie and am not very comfortable in python. Could you please be more specific. Thanks a lot..!!

Comment: @user3332520 Specific about what? This is code. You run it, you see its output, and that output is **exactly** what you asked for -- extracted attributes and values for all elements.

Comment: Note that if you don't have `lxml` installed, you may need to do so. If you're on a Linux operating system, it should already be available as a package, typically called something like `python-lxml` or `python2-lxml`. If you're on Windows, you can download it from http://lxml.de/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made a few corrections and got i what i want..!!

Comment: @user3332520, glad to hear. If this answer helped you, please consider marking it accepted and upvoting.

Comment: When i run the above given XML file i get blank spaces inbetween. Actually i am going to use the extracted values, so even the blank spaces are included. That will affect my result. Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: The blank spaces are part of the file, thus part of your raw data. If you want to know how to clean up the data, that's a different question, and should be asked separately. (A hint, though -- look at `string.strip()`).